# java-script parsing tagged output with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to parse this telnet output from my game. I have tried to use regex but it will not capture anything and keeps returning null. I have tried several different examples from searching but none work. below would be my string, I want to capture between **< motd>** and **< /motd>** and later on I would like to capture all **< item ...>** in the **< players>** tag. I have sent the output of **str** to console and it all shows up as expected. This is the regex i am currently trying that returns null.

```
    var result = str.match( /<motd>(.|\n|\r\n)*?<\/motd>/g );
    console.log(result);
```

and the str:

```
    <motd>
    Welcome to MUD

    ***************
    UPDATE May 11, 2018 Interface v31.2
    ***************
    NEW INTERFACE: v31.2 is online!

    Changes to INTERFACE:
    Larger Message Queue
    Built-in, auto-synced Tick Timer.
    Junk/Sell/Drop on multiple items now works for entire stack of items.
    New Mob Art
    Ungroup Button fixed.

    ****
    NEW EDITABLE COMMAND ENTRY BOX!!
    ****

    Changes to GAME:
    Miscellaneous small fixes to make the interface function cleaner.
    Shop and Inventory Parsing bugs (overflow) improved heavily.
    New items, it's a surprise. Hint: Think Orc Dreams.
    Fixed small bugs in room art.
    New character creation bug (chars being reset to level 1) fixed.
    Score made more detailed on enchantments.
    Large quantity junking fixed.
    Follow Spam Removed. You're welcome. You may grovel now.
    Stealing from newbies fixed. Thanks to the guy who reported that!
    Limbo bugs fixed, including not being able to idle out.
    Quicklevelling fixed. We don't recommend you make this code tell us what you're doing.
    Dark showing properly on various spells/light/sleep/combat changes.
    Orc jail meat collector fixed.
    </motd>
    <paiddays 0>
    <players>
    <item Time 1 ~ 1409 0 1 150532 171205 171959 150801 170762 152159 2556 1453 170023 0>
    <item Mep 1 ~ 1509 0 1 555 0 1959 0 750 2153 2555 0 4 0>
    <item ZugZug 1 ~ 9025 3 1 551 1210 142010 803 140750 142150 2550 171453 145 0>
    <players>
    <playername>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the regex:

```
/<motd>[^<>]*?<\/motd>/igm
```

Here:

1. i : is to ignore case
2. g : is for global search
3. m : for multiple line
   matching

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM parser. The closest to your question is JQuery DOM parser.

```
var myOut = $.parseXML(str);   

var items = $(myOut).find('item');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, parseHTML will work even if the tags are not valid html?  Also your example breaks with an ***caught exception: TypeError: item is not a function***

Comment: Please see the edited answer. It is parseXML - not parseHTML.

Comment: Getting an error because the tags are not valid XML, they are custom tags from telnet.   ***caught exception: Error: Invalid XML: < item>***

Comment: XML tags are custom. You cna put anything as XML tags. The problem is that the telnet output doesn't have proper </closing> tags. Do you control the telnet output?